# Netsuite Invoice / GL entry

Tags: netsuite

I have a unique situation where we need to assign different GL Account when we create an invoice. For now, the first part is done. I created 2 custom fields:
COGS and Income. The user can pick it from the list, save it, etc. Users are fine with it.

However the GL transaction is still with the original Account. I want to write to the GL using the accounts entered on the invoice.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a developer or you know SuiteScript, you can use Custom GL Plugin for this.

Comment: I have already added the fields COGS / Income to the screen, so far everything is fine but now I want to write to the GL. Based on what I found it will write to the default GL, then I will have to write the new GL in a different line. Do you have any example anywhere ? You can reach me directly at markwagner550@gmail.com.

Comment: Download the PDF file found at this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G3mo_6xAQbfv_gN7Bj9g48417I0x7CjJ.  It should contain all the info you need regarding custom gl plugin